# CSS variables use in Vue

Tags: css, vue.js, global-variables, css-variables

Is it possible to use pure CSS variables with Vue without having to link any stylesheets or use SASS/PostCSS? Unsure why I'm unable to get this to work in its most basic form.

```
<template>
   <div id="test">
        TEST
    </div>
</template> 
<style scoped> 
   :root {
   --var-txt-color: #c1d32f;
   }

 #test {
 color: var(--var-txt-color);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: what if you use something else than :root? try `body` or a container element

Comment: I just tried using a body tag but that did not work. Could it be that because its a component and not on the main App.vue causes it to not understand the :root? 

This is the component in particular I'm trying to get to work on:  
https://github.com/bencasalino/nba-timeline-project/blob/master/src/views/About.vue

Comment: I don't know as I know CSS variable but not experienced with Vue.js ... if you are able to give a link with the working app I can help you by looking at the generated code

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This won't work as expected because of `scoped` attribute for stylesheet. Example above compiles into:

```
[data-v-4cc5a608]:root {
  --var-txt-color: #f00;
}
```

And, as you understand, it will not target actual `:root` element.

It can be solved by:

- Not using `scoped` attribute for this stylesheet. Notice that it may cause styles conflict with other variables declarations for `:root` element.
- Using current component's wrapping element as root. If we declare variables this way:

  ```
  .test {
    --var-txt-color: #c1d32f;
    color: var(--var-txt-color);
  }

  .test-child-node {
    background-color: var(--var-txt-color);
  }
  ```

Then it will can reuse variables for other elements of the same component. But still, it won't be possible to use declared variables inside child components without removing `scoped`, if it is the case.

Comment: Ended up using SASS, but the fact that its 'scoped' makes sense on why its not working, thank you so much!

Answer (score 40):

I know you highlighted "without having to link any stylesheet", but I run into the same issue and there is a simple option - use just one external css file and include it in your App.vue, then you can access the variables anywhere else, in scoped styles as well.

variables.css

```
:root {
  --font-family: "Roboto", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif;
  --primary-color: #333a4b;
}
```

App.vue

```
<style>
  @import './assets/styles/variables.css';
</style>
```

LandingView.vue

```
<style scoped>
  #landing-view {
    font-family: var(--font-family);
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    color: var(--primary-color);
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Would you be able to somehow access the css variables in the script tag too? or vice versa?

Comment: This is by far the cleanest solution I have found for this problem. Good job.

Answer (score 12):

Why not just use this?

```
<style scoped>
  * {
    --var-txt-color: #c1d32f;
  }
</style>
```

The generated CSS is:

```
*[data-v-d235d782] {
  --var-txt-color: #c1d32f;
}
```

This has been working for me.

I just discovered that it looks like this also works, using the "[deep selector](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)"

```
>>>  {
  --var-txt-color: #c1d32f;
}
```

Generated CSS is:

```
[data-v-d235d782] {
  --var-txt-color: #c1d32f;
}
```

I think I like this method more.

Comment: thx. I like this way. simple and variables are available within my component.

Comment: Worked beautifully for me

Answer (score 6):

One workaround is to define them under a non-scoped `style` element like the following. However one thing to note here is, these variables will be exposed to other `Vue` components as well.

```
<style>
  :root {
     --var-txt-color: #c1d32f;
  }
</style>

<style scoped>
  #test {
     color: var(--var-txt-color);
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 6):

Late answer - Here is a working example with css vars derived from standard vue structures.

```
<template>
  <div>
  <component :is="'style'">
    :root {
    --color: {{ color }};
    --text-decoration: {{ textDecoration }};
    --font-size: {{ fontSize }};
    }
  </component>
    <p>example</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {

  props:{
    color: {
      type: String,
      default: '#990000'
    }
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
      textDecoration: 'underline'
    }
  },

  computed: {
    fontSize: function (){
      return Math.round(Math.random() * (5 - 1) + 1) + 'em';
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
p{
  color: var(--color);
  text-decoration: var(--text-decoration);
  font-size: var(--font-size);
}
</style>
```

Starting from the top...

- Vue must have 1 root element, so I needed a div tag in order to include a sample p tag.  However, you can just use the component-is-style tag and get rid of the div and p tags.  Note the need for extra quotations "'style'".
- The normal vue style tag can be scoped or not - as needed.

Answer (score 5):

Well, now you can use CSS variable injection.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="text">hello</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
        return {
            color: 'red',
            font: {
                weight: '800'
            }
        }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>
  .text {
    color: v-bind(color);
    font-weight: v-bind('font.weight');
  }
</style>
```

Those styles are also both reactive and scoped. There won't be any unintended inheritance issues. Vue manages the CSS variables for you.

You can take a look at the RFC [here](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/pull/231).